# Is there a way to register services in app.config in mvvm light?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, mvvm-light

I'm trying to load a data for my WPF application using  simpleioc of Viewmodellocator. But the problem with viewmodellocator is, each time you change the code you have to recompile the application. If there was a way to register services in app.config that would be great.

Comment: So what's the problem with recompiling?

Comment: I have wpf application in many different location and so if there is changes in the service I'll have to recompile and deploy in all those locations. So if there was a way to change in app.config, I won't have to redeploy my app.

Comment: But you'll still have to deploy the new app.config? (Given, it would be possible to do)

Comment: If you change a service a live app consumes then i don't see how just changing some config would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

MVVM Light by default uses SimpleIoC, which does not support loading registration information from XML configuration files. If you need to do that, you can replace default IoC container with Unity (by Microsoft), which does support configuration files.

An article that explains how to do this can be seen in [this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff660935(v=pandp.20)#_Loading_the_Configuration).

To see how you can use Unity with MVVM Light, check this [CodeProject article](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/655515/Integrating-Unity-Container-with-MVVM-Light-Framew)

Comment: Thanks this was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @RajonTanducar: Consider marking it as answer if this helped you solve your problem.